# Sometimes signal not received to signal handler

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, signals, signal-handling

I'm sending say 100 signal (SIGINT) from terminal in while loop continuously, as i have register signal handler for this signal, so any signal comes either in auxiliary thread or main thread (as signal disposition is shared by all threads) should print "caught signal: ..." message as output every time i send the signal. but i observed out of 100, some random less no of times say 95, 84 times being this message printed. can some one please explain why all 100 signal is not being printed and how to print all 100 signal with below code.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Signal Handler for entire Process (shared by all threads) 

void signalHandler(int param)
{
  printf("Caught signal: %d ", param);
}

void *childFun(void *arg)
{
  // Register signal Handler here 
  struct sigaction childpsa;
  childpsa.sa_handler = signalHandler;
  sigaction(SIGTERM, &childpsa, NULL);
  sigaction(SIGHUP, &childpsa, NULL);
  sigaction(SIGINT, &childpsa, NULL);
  sigaction(SIGCONT, &childpsa, NULL);
  sigaction(SIGTSTP, &childpsa, NULL);

  while (1) {
    // doSomething in while loop
  }
}

int main(void)
{

  // create a auxiliary thread here
  pthread_t child_threadId;
  int err = pthread_create(&child_threadId, NULL, &childFun, NULL);

  while (1) {
    // main program do something 
  }

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Please post the actual example. Your code does not print anything to the terminal because of line buffering, and using `printf` in signal handlers is typically invalid anyway because it is not an async-signal-safe function.

Comment: Hi Florian, .
signalHandler is being called in parallel by main thread and auxiliary thread and even this function may be called in parallel by same thread also. am i right ?
How can i track/print  no. of times this function is called overall by all threads. ?
definitely mutex will not work to track counter. (also i have give tried using mutex,).

e.g.. 
    // global varible 
    int count = 0;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;

   void signalHandler(int param)
   {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      count++
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   }

Comment: Also note that 'normal' POSIX signals and real-time signals differ. See signal (7) manpage: 'Multiple  instances of real-time signals can be queued.  By contrast, if multiple instances of a standard signal are delivered
           while that signal is currently blocked, then only one instance is queued.' Not sure if this is relevant in your case, though.

Comment: @LawKumar, you could use atomics to count signals, and use `write` (an async-signal-safe function) to write to standard output.

Answer (score 0):

Most of Linux implementation doesn't support queueing of signal, so if a process receives same signal 'x' number of times, it will be called only once.

Also you shouldn't use function like printf inside signal handler(instead use some counters(an integer) that increments for every invocation )

**Except**

POSIX.1 allows the system to deliver the signal either once or more than once in case a blocked signal is generated more than once before the process unblocks the signal. If the system delivers the signal more than once, we say that the signals are queued. Most UNIX systems, however, do not queue signals unless they support the real-time extensions to POSIX.1. Instead, the UNIX kernel simply delivers the signal once. [p336]

https://notes.shichao.io/apue/ch10/#reliable-signal-terminology-and-semantics